# Run/Exclude Specific Tests in Build Definition Team Foundation Server 2015

Tags: tfs, xunit, tfs-2015

In one of our build definitions I'm trying to configure a 'Visual Studio Test' build step to run a specific set of tests.

There is a 'Test Filter critera' box (below) but this doesn't seem to have any effect, running all tests regardless. It's not like the search filter box in Test Explorer in VS2015, and there are some references to a 'TestCaseFilter' but this doesn't apply here (and might be TFS2012 only).

[image: TFS build definition Visual Studio Test configuration]

Can this be used to actually filter tests, or should I be doing it some other way (e.g. provide a settings file?)

FWIW we're using Xunit for our unit tests.

Comment: It is December now, and it does work the build with `TestCategory=BuildTime` test setup when I have my tests marked by `[TestCategory("BuildTime")]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test Filter Criteria** filters tests from within the test assembly files. This option works the same way as the console option `/TestCaseFilter of vstest.console.exe`, you can test with vstest.console.exe command line to see whether it works.

As an alternate, you can specify the tests in **Test Assembly**. This field specifies the test assemblies(s) from which the tests should be picked.

- Wildcards can be used
- Multiple paths can be specified separated by a semicolon
- Paths are relative to the Sources Directory

Comment: While this doesn't explain why the Test Filter Criteria doesn't work, moving tests to separate assemblies then using the 'Test Assembly' filter does work as expected and is an acceptable workaround. The alternative would be to have a separate build configuration and use pre-processor statements to enable/disable tests.

Answer (score 7):

If the goal is to exclude a test of tests from a run that can be accomplished via

> `TestCategory!={name}`

In my case I typically use Integration or Manual to indicate a non-CI test so my filter is

> `TestCategory!=Integration&TestCategory!=Manual`

Answer (score 2):

The Test Filter Criteria field is the best way to filter tests.  You do have to add an attribute to your tests to categorize your tests.  Here is post that explains this feature:

https://dotnetcatch.com/2016/03/11/vststfs-visual-studio-test-task-filter-criteria/

Comment: I don't have 'TestCategory' available like that post does in the code example... I'm wondering if this only applies to 'mstest'? We're using xUnit which might have different syntax for filtering... I'm still trying to get my head round these testing frameworks.

Comment: Sorry you didn't mention you were using nUnit.  Based on this article nUnit should be supported as well using the "Category" attribute.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/06/11/part-3-unit-testing-with-traits-and-code-coverage-in-visual-studio-2012-using-the-tfs-build-and-the-new-nuget-adapter-approach/

Comment: I didn't mention nUnit... but did mention I was using xUnit in the original question :) I'll have a look at that article...

Comment: Okay, I'm already using headers like '[Trait("Category", "Integration")]' for my (xUnit) tests, and I'd assume I need to put 'TestCategory=Integration' in the Test Filter criteria, however this has no effect. In fact even if I put in garbage in there it still runs (I can see said garbage being passed as an a TestCaseFilter argument to vstest.console.exe in the build log).

Answer (score 1):

For those (like me) with a more specific issue, where all the tests of a certain project have to be excluded, use the following statement in the "Test Assemblies" field:

```
!**\*[ProjectName]*.dll
```

In my case, I have one project that contains a lot of UI tests which are set up as unit tests. Initially the agent would try to run these tests as well, while they should only run at a specific release. An example of the fix:

[image: Fix example]

This makes sure all the tests within that project are ignored, even though the dll contains "tests" in the name.